# Built-in search tool in shell scripts

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have an input file "B", containing line numbers referring to specific
lines in file "A". I need to search for a text pattern using the line
numbers in "B", e.g. first 3 lines of B will be:

```
385
527
547
```

So I need to check whether the "pattern" is present between 386 and 526,
528 and 548 in the file "A". I can do this with some complex programming
and looping with the help of `awk` etc., but I want to know the built-in
tools and options available in Unix (Solaris) for searching, to make my
code simple, e.g., if there is a tool or option to search a pattern
between a given line range it will be useful.

Comment: i want to search the pattern in the file A , between the numbers which present the file "B"
pattern in file A between "line 1 and line 2" in file B
patern in file A between "line 2 and line 3" in file B

Comment: That comment should become an edit of the question.

Comment: you are correct tom , was struggling to find how to edit the question, so went for this.

Answer (score 0):

No looping or complexity needed for awk to match (and print) in a range:

```
awk 'NR>start && NR<end && /pattern/'
```

A bit trickier to convert file B content to the right `awk` condition, but this does it:

```
echo "($(awk 'NR==1{r1=$1;next}
              NR>2{printf"||"}
              {printf"(NR>%d&&NR<%d)",r1,$1;r1=$1}
              END{if(NR<2)printf"0"}' B))&&/yourpattern/"|
  awk -f- A
```

Perhaps slightly simpler would be to pre-filter the ranges using sed, and then grep for the pattern:

```
awk 'NR==1{r1=$1;next}
     $1>r1+1{printf"%d,%dp\n",r1+1,$1-1;r1=$1}' B|
  sed -nf- A|
  grep 'yourpattern'
```

Comment: The awk version is slightly better in the error case of a duplicated (or sequential) range number in file B. I think the sed version would *include* the (first) line number where the awk version would properly exclude it.

Comment: really thanks for your help. am going through your code , give me few mins , i will surely get back . with my results and command!

Comment: as per your algorithm 
fetch the nth and n+1th line number for B and search for the pattern between these line numbers in A , am i rite?

Comment: You can see what it is trying to do by just running the B part (everything before the first `|`) and checking the expression, to see if it is what you expect for line-range conditions.

Comment: bit confused on 
----- \)\&\&/your_pattern/ ---- because "yourpattern" i can understnad , but not these slashes and ampersands(&)

Comment: yea , just did it , you are a magic man !! (NR>385&&NR<537)||(NR>537&&NR<539)||(NR>539&&NR<547) ......
here goes the o/p of the B part.. so as per your first answer
awk 'NR>start && NR<end && /pattern/' -----> this should be the awk to be actually executed and here we prepared the  'NR>start && NR<end using the B part

Comment: The slashes are escaping the `&` from the shell, so that `&&` is what awk sees, per the first example line. (`&` and `(` have special meaning to the shell). Actually double-quoting works just as well, and may be the clearer way; I will update accordingly.

Comment: ok now got ..
)\&\&/ --> "\" is used coz & is a special character. and when we come to the last part "awk -f- A" this will for instance will use "NR>385&&NR" on "file A" to search the match.
if this is the case... wats the -f- option does... jus that one doubt remains...

Comment: The `-f` option to awk (and sed) tells it to read its commands from a file. The `-` for the "file name" tells if to read (its commands) from standard input, i.e. the pipe.

Comment: I have corrected the error condition in the sed version by adding a guard condition against it (`$1>r1+1`).

Comment: There was an unhandled edge condition, lines in B < 2, in the awk version, now corrected (via `END` action).

Comment: thanks a lot its solved my problem . am editing my question again . i should have done this first itself some how , i missed it and sorry for extending this discussion
the final requirement is to store the line ranges for which  a match is found say eg : NR>385&&NR<537 -- match will bethere in file A
(NR>537&&NR<539) -- match may not be there in  file A 
so i need to extract the first pair and store in a  file .
basically i need to know any awk variable is there to check whether match is found in a given range or not. based on that i will store the ranges in a file.

Comment: Edit the question with a sample of the exact desired output format given the B shown, or create a new question, and I'll give it a go. (That is a different question: "Detecting line range of search matches".)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805839/detecting-the-range-of-the-matches-shell-script
hi jeff ,
i have created a new question , detailing the req and the so far work done , history everything. even am searching simultaniously. thanks for your help sir.