# Detecting the range of the matches - shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, logfile

I have a file A and B .

- A contains log entries
- B contains some line numbers which in turn are some specific line numbers

referring the log file

I have an awk program like this:

```
echo "($(awk 'NR==1{r1=$1;next}
              NR>2{printf"||"}
              {printf"(NR>%d&&NR<%d)",r1,$1;r1=$1}' B))&&/mypattern/"|
  awk -f- A
       ---> (courtesy jeff y from stack flow )
```

[in this link you can find the requirement for which the above script is born](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799002/built-in-search-tool-in-shell-scripts)

the part before the "|" generates the ranges to be search in file A.
eg : `(NR>385&&NR<537)||(NR>537&&NR<539)||(NR>539&&NR<547)|`
these are some of the ranges which can be generated by the part before "|"
I need to store the ranges  for which "mypattern" has a match in a sep file ora variable ate last
say eg `NR>385&&NR<537`  --> this range on file A may not have  a match according to my pattern where as (`NR>539&&NR<547` this may have 
so any idea to check whether a match had happened , if so to store the NR corresponding NR values in side a file .

Comment: I still need to see a code block with the exact output required to meet whatever your final goal is. And what is that final goal by the way? What is this all for ultimately? Final end product.

Comment: 1.FILE A -- log file , FILE B -- line numbers of some specific lines in the log file . (these numbers are extracted from the FILE A  by searching the text "Exception"(and ignoring some unnecessary matches) .)
2. by using  FILE B am trying to find whether the text "tms" is present between the ranges . 
in other words .  am finding EXCEPTIONS which are RELATED TO TMS alone.
for the above purpose am giving  
*line ranges (these are got from FILE B for which the code is there above)
*match pattern 
* FILE A 
as i/p to the awk. )
its now prinitng the matches. full code am giving below.

Comment: grep -n  "Exception" FILE_A  | grep -v "ExceptionUnparseable date" | cut -d ":" -f1 > FILE_B
echo "($(awk 'NR==1{r1=$1;next}
              NR>2{printf"||"}
              {printf"(NR>%d&&NR<%d)",r1,$1;r1=$1}' FILE_B )) && /tms/" | awk -f- FILE_A


sample output now :
 at com.tms.cad.aror.service.email.ecn...

 at com.tms.cad.aror.service.eng.ecn.helper.EcnEmailHelper....
.....


final goal : 
if i get the match ranges responsible for the above o/p . eg
385,537 - 537,539 -> i will take 385th and 537 th lines from FILE A.

Comment: Yes, but if you get, let's say, a single line of output telling you the only range in which there was a tms match, say `385-537`, *what are you going to do with that output then*?

Comment: i will  get the 385th line from the  FILE_A and 384th also .  like wise.

1.the responsbile exception for the TMS  application
2.the time in which the exception  occurred (which the prev line , in this example its 384)

Comment: i have also tried a lot. from my obeservation.
as we are converting the text in the FILE_B as range and making it as a input (from console) by giving -f- option there is no way ti print those ranges which are responsible  in this statement i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Given your clarification in comments, I would propose a solution that only takes one pass through FILE_A with awk, rather than trying to extract and use line numbers and ranges numerically (FILE_B) in multiple passes:

```
awk '/Exception/ && !/ExceptionUnparseable date/ {
       haveEx="yes"; ex=$0; exDate=last; haveMatch=""}
     haveEx && /tms/ {
       haveMatch="yes"; print exDate; print ex; haveEx=""}
     haveMatch && /tms/ {print}
     {last = $0} ' FILE_A
```

Or, if you don't need to see the lines that do match the pattern:

```
awk '/Exception/ && !/ExceptionUnparseable date/ {
       haveEx="yes"; ex=$0; exDate=last}
     haveEx && /tms/ {
       print exDate; print ex; haveEx=""}
     {last = $0} ' FILE_A
```

Comment: going through it. defintly it will take atleast 10 mins! i will get back sure.

Comment: you helped a lot. ! u deserve a pay from me sure! i went through the snip completely (both the  codes).   algorithm is , search for pattern one and have a marking  text "yes" . search for pattern 2 having tms and "yes".  till this part am clear. but the last part of setting havex="" and assigning last=$0 is what am unclear. last is a keyword i guess. and you are assiggning the rwo value to it . so kind of confused at the climax.! . but its working perfect.!!!

Comment: `last` is just an awk variable to store the previous record so that it is available (for setting exDate) when an exception line is found.

Comment: yes i got the uage of "last in getting the date `awk '/Exception/ && !/ExceptionUnparseable date/ {
       haveEx="yes"; ex=$0; exDate=last; haveMatch=""}
     haveEx && /tms/ {
       haveMatch="yes"; print exDate; print ex; ------> haveEx=""<----} 
     haveMatch && /tms/ {print}
   ----> {last = $0} <----- ' FILE_A` 
two ofthe arrow marked part is only am unclear . like setting the havEx to empty. and assigning the last to $0

Comment: `haveEx=""` stops the code from printing the same date+exception lines for every "tms" line of the exception (only the first "tms" it finds).

Comment: thanks a lot. i got cleared, btw i followed your blog too. :) commented there